# AngularJS: SubTotals and Totals

Tags: angularjs

I have coded myself into a corner and can't figure out **how to calculate the subtotals (per crop) and totals (all crops)**. I have the expected values hard-coded right now but need to figure out how to calculate them.

[I have a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fSZ7wUzySDNm1yqhxb2x?p=preview).

I am using budget.json to simulate the call to the database in the factory (defined in budget.js). The BudgetsController is also defined in budget.js.

The hard-coded totals begin at line 35 of budgets.js. I tried several of the LoDash methods to calculate the totals but can't seem to find the pattern that I can replicate for each crop and I know the Totals total would follow the same pattern but just using the subtotals.

Any help is appreciated!

CODE of budget.js:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('ARM')
    .factory('ExpensesFactory', function ExpensesFactory(
      $http, $q
    ) {

      return {
        getBudget: getBudget
      };

      function getBudget(id){
        return $http.get('budget.json');
      }

    })
      .controller('BudgetsController', BudgetsController);

    BudgetsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ExpensesFactory'];

    function BudgetsController(
        $scope, ExpensesFactory
    ){
      ExpensesFactory.getBudget('1')
        .then(function success(rsp){
          var arr = rsp.data;
          var flattened = _.flatten(arr);

          var grped = _.groupBy(flattened, function(item) {
            return item.crop;
          });
          $scope.uses = grped;

          //TODO: Crop and Loan Budget Totals
          $scope.uses.totals = [
            //CORN
            [
              {
                "arm": 178,
                "dist": 197.91,
                "other": 115,
                "peracre": 490.91,
                "calc_arm": 61837.2,
                "calc_dist": 68753.934,
                "calc_other": 39951,
                "calc_total": 170542.134
              }
            ],
            //SOYBEANS
            [
              {
                "arm": 145,
                "dist": 69.73,
                "other": 74.35,
                "peracre": 289.08,
                "calc_arm": 84143.5,
                "calc_dist": 40464.319,
                "calc_other": 43145.305,
                "calc_total": 167753.124
              }
            ],
            //SORGHUM
            [
              {
                "arm": 0,
                "dist": 0,
                "other": 0,
                "peracre": 0,
                "calc_arm": 0,
                "calc_dist": 0,
                "calc_other": 0,
                "calc_total": 0
              }
            ],
            //WHEAT
            [
              {
                "arm": 0,
                "dist": 0,
                "other": 0,
                "peracre": 0,
                "calc_arm": 0,
                "calc_dist": 0,
                "calc_other": 0,
                "calc_total": 0
              }
            ],
            //COTTON
            [ 
              {
              "arm": 0,
              "dist": 0,
              "other": 0,
              "peracre": 0,
              "calc_arm": 0,
              "calc_dist": 0,
              "calc_other": 0,
              "calc_total": 0
            }
            ],
            //RICE
            [
              {
                "arm": 0,
                "dist": 0,
                "other": 0,
                "peracre": 0,
                "calc_arm": 0,
                "calc_dist": 0,
                "calc_other": 0,
                "calc_total": 0
              }
            ],
            //PEANUTS
            [
              {
                "arm": 0,
                "dist": 0,
                "other": 0,
                "peracre": 0,
                "calc_arm": 0,
                "calc_dist": 0,
                "calc_other": 0,
                "calc_total": 0
              }
            ],
            //SUGAR CANE
            [ 
              {
              "arm": 0,
              "dist": 0,
              "other": 0,
              "peracre": 0,
              "calc_arm": 0,
              "calc_dist": 0,
              "calc_other": 0,
              "calc_total": 0
            }
            ],
            //TOTALS
            [ 
              {
                "arm": 0,
                "dist": 0,
                "other": 0,
                "peracre": 0,
                "calc_arm": 155999,
                "calc_dist": 36530,
                "calc_other": 87223,
                "calc_total": 279752
              }
            ]
          ];

          var uniqExp = _.uniq(_.pluck(flattened, 'expense'));
          $scope.exp = uniqExp;
        });
    } // end BudgetsController fn
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what you've got:

1. _.groupBy: returns an object whose keys are crop's names;
2. _.map: iterates over `grped` keys (crop names) and returns an array;
3. item.reduce(): native array method, accumulates some values through the whole array

   1. current: reduces passes a different element from array, each time;
   2. previous: this one we're are in control, the first time it contains the value of the second `reduce()` parameter, this is why I've passed an fixed object. This object is modified each iteration.

More information about `Array.prototype.reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Sample:

```
      $scope.uses = _.map(grped, function (item, key) {
        return item.reduce(function (previous, current) {
          // in the nth iteration, each previous property will be equal to sum(arr[0].property...arr[n-1].property)
          previous.arm += current.arm;
          previous.dist += current.dist;
          previous.other += current.other;
          // other fields should be summed here

          // remember to return the accumulator
          return previous;
        },
          /* initialize each property to zero, otherwize it won't work */ 
          {crop: key, arm: 0, dist: 0, other: 0});
      });
```

Comment: could you explain a bit your use of previous and current?

Comment: GREAT for SubTotals (http://plnkr.co/edit/fSZ7wUzySDNm1yqhxb2x?p=preview) but I'm not sure how to get the TOTALS now that I have the SubTotals. I thought I could just do the same thing but instead pass in $scope.uses.total but that's not working for me.

Comment: You were almost there, but you should model in your mind (or debug step-by-step) why a map() is used around each reduce(). In case of totals, you just need the reduce step. a final note, avoid setting totals to a property of an array, save it directly to $scope. http://plnkr.co/edit/GeYpw7c0d6I3fgXy7lFF?p=preview